# Set up many to many associations between classes in single inheritance table and another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, associations, single-table-inheritance

I have a join table named Relations in a many to many relationship between departments and researchers.

I want to be able to get a list of students by doing `Department.find(1).students` but I am getting `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError (Could not find the source association(s) :students in model Researcher. Try 'has_many :students, :through => :researchers, :source => <name>'.)`

Why isn't it using the scope from the table Researcher?

```rb
class Department < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :relations
  has_many :researchers, through: :relations
  has_many :students, source: :students, through: :researchers
  has_many :advisors, source: :advisors, through: :researchers
end

class Relation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :researcher
  belongs_to :department
end

class Reseacher < ApplicationRecord
  scope :students, -> { where(type: 'Student') }
  scope :advisors, -> { where(type: 'Advisor') }
end

class Student < Researcher
  has_many :relations, foreign_key: :department_id
  has_many :departments, through: :relations
end

class Advisor < Researcher
  has_many :relations, foreign_key: :department_id
  has_many :departments, through: :relations
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`source:` option expects an association as argument. Internally, rails [runs](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.3/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb#L814) a reflection on the argument, like:

```rb
# source: :students, through: :researchers
>> Researcher.reflect_on_association(:students)
=> nil
```

Before fixing *has_many :students* association, a few things to note:

```
has_many :students,     # will look for `students` association in the intermediate
                        # model unless source is specified; intermediate model is
                        # determined by reflecting on through option `:researchers`
                        #
                        #   reflect_on_association(:researchers).klass # => Researcher

  through: :researchers # can't go through `researchers`; already there.
                        # `Student` is a `Researcher`.

  source: :students,    # there is no `students` association in `Researcher` class.
                        #
                        #   reflect_on_association(:researchers).klass
                        #     .reflect_on_association(:students) # => nil
```

To fix the association we can use `scope` argument of `has_many` method:

```
has_many(name, scope = nil, **options, &extension)
#              ^ pass a proc as a second argument
```

```
class Department < ApplicationRecord
  # NOTE: add `dependent: :destroy` option to destroy corresponding Relations
  #       when destroying a Department 
  has_many :relations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :researchers, through: :relations

  has_many :students, 
    -> { where(type: "Student") }, # scope the associated model

    through: :relations,           # relevant association is in Relation model

    source:  :researcher           # look for `researcher` association in Relation.
                                   # instead of `student`

  # NOTE: use existing scope from another model
  has_many :advisors,
    -> { advisors },               # this runs in the source class.
    through: :relations,           #                    |
    source:  :researcher           # <------------------'
                                   # Researcher has `advisors` class method,
                                   # defined by `scope: :advisors`.
end
```

Now, we need to fix the association between `Relation` and `Researcher`:

```
# NOTE: what if you need another "relation" class to make another many-to-many association.
# TODO: call this something a bit more descriptive like `DepartmentStaff`
#       or use the conventional `DepartmentResearcher`.
class Relation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :researcher
  belongs_to :department
end

class Researcher < ApplicationRecord
  scope :students, -> { where(type: "Student") }
  scope :advisors, -> { where(type: "Advisor") }

  # NOTE: `has_many :relations` is the opposite of `belongs_to :researcher`
  #       `foreign_key` is `researcher_id` which is the default and
  #       should not be changed.
  # has_many :relations, foreign_key: :department_id

  has_many :relations, dependent: :destroy        # <--.
  has_many :departments, through: :relations      # <--|
end                                               #    |
                                                  #    |
class Student < Researcher                        #    |
  # NOTE: no need to duplicate these; put it in the parent class.
  # has_many :relations
  # has_many :departments, through: :relations
end

class Advisor < Researcher
end
```

```
>> Relation.create!([{researcher: Student.new, department: Department.create},{researcher: Advisor.new, department: Department.first}])

>> Department.first.students
=> [#<Student:0x00007f7f78ae5f98 id: 1, type: "Student">]

>> Department.first.advisors        
=> [#<Advisor:0x00007f7f789a9b20 id: 2, type: "Advisor">]

>> Department.first.researchers                                                            
=> [#<Student:0x00007f7f786bdc90 id: 1, type: "Student">, #<Advisor:0x00007f7f786bd858 id: 2, type: "Advisor">]
```

---

You can also let rails do the work by defining additional associations in `Relation`, no scope required:

```
class Relation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :researcher
  belongs_to :department

  belongs_to :student, foreign_key: :researcher_id, optional: true
  belongs_to :advisor, foreign_key: :researcher_id, optional: true
end

class Department < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :relations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :researchers, through: :relations

  has_many :students, through: :relations
  has_many :advisors, through: :relations
end
```

---

*https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association*

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope*

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many*

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_association*

Comment: As for the second approach, the belong_to's in the Relation table will enforce having both student and advisor. So the first one ended up working better for me :)

Comment: oh, right. the additional associations should be optional: `belongs_to :student, foreign_key: :researcher_id, optional: true`